# Master/Detail DataGridViews not populating Details DataGridView

Tags: winforms, entity-framework, dbcontext

I'm using the following technologies: WinForms, Entity Framework 4.4 (5.0 on .NET 4.0), DBContext

I have (what I think is) a very simple Master/Details form, that actually worked just fine before I upgraded from EF 4.0 to EF 4.4. Now, for some reason, the Details DataGridView simply doesn't populate with any data!

Here's my auto-generated schema code:

```
public partial class RoadMapping
{
    public RoadMapping()
    {
        this.RoadCharacteristics = new HashSet<RoadCharacteristic>();
    }

    public int RoadMappingID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<RoadCharacteristic> RoadCharacteristics { get; set; }
}

public partial class RoadCharacteristic
{
    public RoadCharacteristic()
    {
    }

    public int RoadCharacteristicID { get; set; }
    public int RoadMappingID { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual RoadMapping RoadMapping { get; set; }
}
```

Here's my code that was working with EF 4.0:

```
SATContext = new SafetyAssessmentToolEntities();

dataGridViewMappings.DataSource = bindingSourceMappings;
dataGridViewDetails.DataSource = bindingSourceDetails;

bindingSourceMappings.DataSource = SATContext.RoadMappings;
bindingSourceDetails.DataSource = bindingSourceMappings;
bindingSourceDetails.DataMember = "RoadCharacteristics";
```

Here's the code that isn't working with EF 4.4:

```
SATContext = new SafetyAssessmentToolEntities();
SATContext.RoadMappings.Load();
SATContext.RoadCharacteristics.Load();

dataGridViewMappings.DataSource = bindingSourceMappings;
dataGridViewDetails.DataSource = bindingSourceDetails;

bindingSourceMappings.DataSource = SATContext.RoadMappings.Local.ToBindingList();
bindingSourceDetails.DataSource = bindingSourceMappings;
bindingSourceDetails.DataMember = "RoadCharacteristics";
```

Please note that `bindingSourceMappings` and `bindingSourceDetails` are declared by the form designer.

I know there are a lot of more advanced and code-intensive ways to make this work, but I can't understand why this very simple way of doing it won't work anymore.

Any suggestions?

---

```
public partial class SafetyAssessmentToolEntities : DbContext
{
    public SafetyAssessmentToolEntities()
        : base("name=SafetyAssessmentToolEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public DbSet<RoadCharacteristic> RoadCharacteristics { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RoadMapping> RoadMappings { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you declare RoadMappings and RoadCharacteristincs in the context? I have this kind of thing working with EF 5, but I dont use the .Load()

Comment: I think this is what you're asking for?

Comment: FYI, I've abandoned this code branch, so I no longer need this question answered. I will leave it up in case some-one wants to post an answer to help others.